How to catch cURL (piped through base64) download failure
I am using cURL to download files and store them in variables (via base64):
output=$(curl -L -o - $url | base64)

The problem is that I don't know how to check if the download was successful (if so, the file should be saved in a variable).

Try
if output=$(set -o pipefail; curl ... | base64); then
  # handle success
else
  # handle failure
fi


One way to determine whether it's successful or not:
output=$(curl -Lsf "$url" | base64); [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo Success || echo Failed: $?

This will either echo Success, or Failed. If not successful the $output variable will be empty.

Thank you for reply but it doesn't work if cURL download a part of file. Output isn't empty and echo returns Success. It happens if I add to curl arguments --speed-time 20 --speed-limit 1. I apologize, I should write about these arguments in the first post.

@user2141238: You're welcome! The answer you chose as accepted won't fail on partial downloads either, you would need additional checks for that.
